# Adding a native method to OpenJDK source code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native-methods

I am trying add a custom native method(free) to OpenJDK source, so I can call that method as System.free() from inside the user Application.

I referred online resources to do so and did following changes :

```
{JDK13ROOT}/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Runtime.java
public static native void free();

{JDK13ROOT}/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java
public static void free() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().free();
}

{JDK13ROOT}/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Runtime.c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Runtime_free(){
     printf("Caught !\n");
}
```

After above changes, I was able to successfully compile the Driver program which directly calls System.free(), and prints **Caught !** after execution.

I want to call JVM_Free() inside Java_java_lang_Runtime_free() as below:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Runtime_free(){
     printf("Caught !\n");
     JVM_Free();
}
```

I have included the declaration in
**{JDK13ROOT}/src/hotspot/share/include/jvm.h**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
JVM_Free(void);
```

And the definition of same in **{JDK13ROOT}/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp**

```
JVM_ENTRY_NO_ENV(void, JVM_Free(void))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_Free");
  printf("SUCCESS\n");
JVM_END
```

I took reference of implementation of GC() and did the same changes., but when I build the program I get the following error.

```
Updating support/modules_libs/java.base/libjava.so due to 1 file(s)
/usr/bin/ld: {JDK13ROOT}/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/support/native/java.base/libjava/Runtime.o: in function `Java_java_lang_Runtime_free':
{JDK13ROOT}src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Runtime.c:71: undefined reference to `JVM_Free'
```

I'm not able to figure out why am I not able to call any functions from Runtime.c.

PS: I also tried adding the native method from System.c instead of Runtime.c and I see the same build failure. What am I missing or doing wrong here ?.

Comment: JOOI, why aren't you just writing this as a JNI shared lib shipped with the app, instead of shoe-horning it into the JRE itsefl?

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for your reply. Could you please how to do that or any links for reference?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symbol (`JVM_Free`) is not exported. Take a look here (t vs. T)

```
> nm libjvm.dylib | grep JVM_GC
000000000041508c T _JVM_GC

vs.

> nm libjvm.dylib | grep JVM_Free
000000000041517a t _JVM_Free
```

in order to export your new symbol, you have to add it here

```
{JDK13ROOT}/make/hotspot/symbols/symbols-unix
```

once it's there, you will be able to "see" it from the outside of `libjvm.dylib` (or `.so`).

Comment: Oo.oO thanks for the answer. I found libjvm.so in {JDK13ROOT}/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/gtest/. It worked!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with Java + native stuff ;) .oOo.