# How to provide an interface to the user to call a custom JDK internal function from the java program?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have implemented a function in OpenJDK(C++) code and want to provide an interface to the user to call that function in her java program.
I think this is different from Java Native Interface(JNI) because the java application would need to call a function in JDK code that interacts with internal classes and data structures.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743716/adding-a-native-method-to-openjdk-source-code/57762731#57762731

Comment: Thank you, @Oo.oO. It addresses my problem.